# Wrapping grid with dynamic

Tags: dynamic

I'm trying to build a sortable grid:

```
sortBy[data_, idx_] := 
  If[idx == 0, data, Sort[data, #1[[idx]] < #2[[idx]] &]];
sortableTable[data_, header_] := DynamicModule[
  {h, sort = 0},
  h = MapIndexed[Button[#1, sort = #2] &, header];
  Dynamic[Grid[Prepend[sortBy[data, sort], h]]]];
sortableTable[
  Table[
    RandomInteger[100], {i, 3}, {j, 4}], 
    {"First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"}]
```

For some reason it is not behaving like I expected: header disappears and sorting doesn't occur. I've tried all sorts of stuff but can't make it work like intended. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: try: `sort = First@#2` in the `MapIndexed`

Comment: Thanks. This was the actual error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
rows = 3;
cols = 4;
data = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {rows, cols}];
names = {"First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"};
sortBy[data_, idx_] := If[idx == 0, data, Sort[data, #1[[idx]] < #2[[idx]] &]];
Dynamic@Grid@Prepend[data, Array[Button[names[[#]], data = sortBy[data, #]] &, cols]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to re-invent `SortBy`.

Stealing ybeltukov solution:

```
Dynamic@Grid@
 Prepend[data, 
         Array[Button[names[[#]],
                      data = SortBy[data, Function[x, #[[x]] &][#]]
                     ] &
               , cols]
        ]
```

Comment: You forgot to localize `x`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I didn't, I was just too lazy to do this. Or frustrated by [recent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31985/5478) where no one cared about localiziing `t` or letter case in `sin` till you posted the answer :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard But I should act like an adult so I've edited it :p

Answer (score 4):

Here is a possibility:

```
SeedRandom[1];
labels = {"First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"};
nrows = 4;
data = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {nrows, Length@labels}];

DynamicModule[{idx = 1},
 Dynamic@Grid[
   Prepend[SortBy[data, #[[idx]] &], 
    MapIndexed[Setter[Dynamic@idx, #2, #1] &, labels]],
   Spacings -> {0, Automatic}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If speed on a large dataset should happen to be an issue (unlikely, since the data are displayed), then this will be faster:

```
DynamicModule[{idx = 1},
 Dynamic@Grid[
   Prepend[data[[Ordering[data[[All, idx]]]]], 
    MapIndexed[Setter[Dynamic@idx, #2, #1] &, labels]],
   Spacings -> {0, Automatic}]
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answers worked for me, but I thought I'd add my tweak to allow clicking twice to toggle reverse sort:

```
names={"matches","p1","p2","diff","factored","gap signature"};
lastSort=0;
disp:=Dynamic[Refresh[Block[{t},Grid[Prepend[tab,Array[Button[names[[#]],t=If[#==lastSort,lastSort=0;-1,lastSort=#;1];data=SortBy[data,Function[x,t #[[x]]&][#]]]&,Length[names]]]]],TrackedSymbols:>{data}]];
```

This gives the buttons the names provided, and `disp` is now a dynamic stand-in for the sortable table.

As an aside, the `Refresh[expr, TrackedSymbols:>{data}]` I've found seems to help `Dynamic` expressions not suck up so much CPU.