# Turn expression into function

Tags: function-construction

I'm new to *Mathematica* and I spent the last hour trying to make the expression

```
expression = 
  3 + 2 cos[t] + 3 cos[2t] + 5 cos[3t] + 7 cos[4t] + 9 sin[t] +  4 sin[3t] + 5 sin[4t]
```

into a function of `t`. I tried

```
f[t_] := expression
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Evaluate` is your friend

```
expression = 
 3 + 2 Cos[t] + 3 Cos[2 t] + 5 Cos[3 t] + 7 Cos[4 t] + 9 Sin[t] + 
 4 Sin[3 t] + 5 Sin[4 t];
f[t_] := Evaluate[expression];
f[0]
```

> 20

Edit:
This is the same as

```
f[t_] = expression;
```

Comment: You can do `f[t_] = expression` which is the same thing. `:=` delays evaluation because it has the `HoldAll` attribute, and `Evaluate` takes precedence over that, so in total it's just `=`

Comment: @ssch Oh yes, of course!

Comment: +1. Just to mention one subtlety: the form `lhs:=Evaluate[rhs]` is, strictly speaking, not fully equivalent to `lhs = rhs`, in terms of how the rules are stored internally. In most cases this does not matter, but in some it does. For example: `a := Evaluate[Range[10]] `. Trying the `Part` assignment will result in an error. Try e.g. `a[[2]] = 1`. This won't happen for direct assignment.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin is there any way to tell whether `a` has been assigned a value via `:=` or via `=`, which, as you say, matters... In the terminology of `General::noval`'s documentation: Is there a way to find out whether `a` *is a delayed value* or `a` *has an immediate value*?

Comment: @masterxilo I am not aware of such method. Doesn't mean that there is no, I may just not know about it.

Comment: @masterxilo, @Leonid ``Language`ExtendedDefinition[a]`` will have a delayed rule as value of `OwnValues` for immediate own value, and a list containing one delayed rule for delayed own value.

Comment: There is a problem with this approach. If you want to do a bit more than turning an expression into a function, e.g., `f[t_]:=Expand[Evalute[expression]]`, then the `Expand` will not take any effect.

Comment: Thank you @ybeltukov .  I was looking for a quick way of simplifying a complicated expression prior to using it for a function definition, such as cases where previous functions are being combined to form a new one.  `f[t_] := Evaluate[expression[t]//Simplify]` or `f[t_] := Evaluate[expression[t]//FullSimplify]` does this nicely.

Answer (score 15):

First, note that `sin` and `cos` are not built-in functions; I shall use `Sin` and `Cos`.

Please see: [Scoping in assigning a derivative](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6664/121)

Typically you do not want to make a definition for a parameter `t` without protecting `t` on the RHS.  That is to say, using `Evaluate` or `f[t] =` can leave `t` to evaluate to its present global value.

If you define `expression` with `:=` you will make sure `t` remains unevaluated there as well.

```
t = "Fail!";

expression := 
  3 + 2 Cos[t] + 3 Cos[2 t] + 5 Cos[3 t] + 7 Cos[4 t] + 9 Sin[t] + 4 Sin[3 t] + 5 Sin[4 t]

Block[{t},
  f[t_] = expression;
]

f[0.7]
```

> ```
> 6.84554
> ```

The method above is automated in the abstraction `localSet` defined here:

- [How to make a function like Set, but with a Block construct for the pattern names](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1992/121)

Answer (score 7):

Using `Evaluate` to make a function is not a robust solution. A true function is one which takes all its input from its arguments and return its result from its last return value and has no side effects out of this.

Here is an example why Evaluate does not make `f[t]` a true function

```
expression = Cos[t] + globalX;
globalX = 1;
f[t_] := Evaluate[expression];
```

In the above, `f[t]` took part of its input (the `t` only) via the argument, but the other part (`x`) was accessed by using a global variable. Accessing global variables from inside a function is not a good way to do things (tm).

It is better to do it the good old fashioned way, and put the body of the function inside the function, and pass it all its input via arguments

```
f[t_, x_] := Cos[t] + x
```

The difference is important. If one writes some Module and uses symbols not passed via arguments and also not local to the module, then the notebook interface will show this symbol with different color. This can be important in telling one something is wrong. This becomes more important when working with lots of functions and more complex program. By Evaluating an external expression, one does not have the advantage of this check.

Compare the color of `x` used by the function in these 4 cases:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and

[image: Mathematica graphics]

a black colored `x` will immediately tell one they are accessing a global `x` (a symbol with different context at least), and to correct this. The third and fourth examples above are true functions, while the first two are not.

Comment: The reason I did it like I presented is that I need to construct trigonometric polynomials starting from coefficients...

Comment: "A true function is one.... " You mean a pure function. Functions in Mathematica do not have to be pure, and as such you can justifiably use Evaluate, however as you note it will not be pure (like a ton of other Mathematica functions are not mind you). But describing it as not a "true" function could cause confusion. Besides this point, purity in Mathematica is a much more complicated issue than in other languages, and an argument could be made that no functions are pure. Even `f[x_]:=x^2` will depend on state and can have side effects.

Comment: @jVincent no, I meant true function, not pure. true function in the mathematical sense. it only acts on its input via arguments, and has local variables and has no side effects other than its return value. A true function does not even allow passing argument by reference. Ada functions used to be true, until Ada 2012 where they relaxed allowing a function to be passed an argument by reference (called in-out). Many in Matematica write functions that are not true functions, where some of its input is passed by arguments and some of its input is global.

Comment: ....on the side effect, it is done by documentation.  Each function should document any side effects it makes. Things like creating a file, or updating a file, and such are considered a side-effect and can't be prevented by the language. But should be documented in the function header, so someone reading this function later on, can see right away what are its side-effects.

Comment: "in the mathematical sense" Then you should add this. You where talking about Mathematica, which is a programming language, thus the correct definition of function is the contextual one. It's like arguing that a child's imaginary giraffe is not "truly" imaginary because you can't square it to yield a negative giraffe. While the names used overlap, the definitions are different, and neither is universally "true".

Comment: "Each function should document any side effects it makes." This is provably impossible in Mathematica, so I'm not sure what your point is?

Answer (score 6):

While other answers are valid, I believe you could just use something as straightforward as

`f = Function[t, Evaluate@expression]`

Let's see how it works:

```
In[1]:= expression = 3 + 2 cos[t] + 9 sin[t]
                       + 3 cos[2t]
                       + 5 cos[3t] + 4 sin[3t]
                       + 7 cos[4t] + 5 sin[4t];
In[2]:= ClearAll[f]

In[3]:= f = Function[t, Evaluate@expression]
Out[3]= Function[t, 3 + 2 cos[t] + 9 sin[t]
                      + 3 cos[2t]
                      + 5 cos[3t] + 4 sin[3t]
                      + 7 cos[4t] + 5 sin[4t]]
```

Then,

```
In[4]:= f[0]
```

evaluates:

```
Out[4]= 3 + 17 cos[0] + 18 sin[0]
```

(Mathematica only has definitions for capitalized `Cos` and `Sin`, that's why no more simplifications for your `expression` are provided.)

You may skip the rest of the answer if this solution is enough for you, and you are not interested in Mathematica subtleties.

---

However, there is a subtle aspect that may cause unexpected problems in the future. `In[3]` would modify the “own values” of symbol `f`:

```
In[5]:= OwnValues[f]
Out[5]= {HoldPattern[f] :>
           Function[t, 
                       3 + 2 cos[t] + 9 sin[t]
                         + 3 cos[2t]
                         + 5 cos[3t] + 4 sin[3t]
                         + 7 cos[4t] + 5 sin[4t]]}
```

and if you try to add some modifications to your definition then, you could unexpectedly bump into error:

```
In[6]:= f[t_, shift_] := shift + f[t]
```

(Check out the `Out[5]` error message if you want.) Definitions like the one in `In[5]` deal with “*down* values” of `f`, contrary to “*own* values”.

You could use a bit more elaborate mechanism for assigning `DownValues`, in case you plan to use `In[6]`-like definitions for `f` extensively in the future:

```
In[7]:= nameToPattern = # :> Pattern[#, Blank[]] &;

In[8]:= defineWithExplicitArguments[listOfArgs_List, f_, expr_] :=
          With[{listOfPatterns = listOfArgs /. nameToPattern /@ listOfArgs}, (
            DownValues@f = DeleteCases[DownValues@f, _[_[_@@listOfPatterns], _], 1];
            Evaluate[f@@listOfPatterns] := expr)]

In[9]:= defineWithExplicitArguments[singleArgument_, f_, expr_] :=
          With[{pattern = singleArgument /. nameToPattern@singleArgument}, (
            DownValues@f = DeleteCases[DownValues@f, _[_[_@pattern], _], 1];
            Evaluate[f@pattern] := expr)]
```

Now, let's remove all definitions for `f`

```
In[10]:= ClearAll[f]
```

and we're free to use `defineWithExplicitArguments` for assigning “down values” to it:

```
In[11]:= defineWithExplicitArguments[t, f, expression]

In[12]:= f[0]
Out[12]= 3 + 17 cos[0] + 18 sin[0]
```

Additional definitions would work, too:

```
In[13]:= f[t_, shift_] := shift + f[t]

In[14]:= f[0, -3]
Out[14]= 17 cos[0] + 18 sin[0]
```

By the way, the `In[13]` definition could be added by means of `defineWithExplicitArguments`, as well. Let's check it:

```
In[15]:= f[t_, shift_] =.
```

Here, we redefined “two-arguments version” of `f`, and it does not calculate the shifted wave anymore:

```
In[16]:= f[0, -3]
Out[16]= f[0, -3]
```

Then,

```
In[17]:= defineWithExplicitArguments[{t, shift}, f, expression + shift]
```

makes it work again:

```
In[18]:= f[0, -3]
Out[18]= 17 cos[0] + 18 sin[0]
```

Comment: Note that at least your first form `Function[t, Evaluate@expression]` does not protect `t` from a global value, should one desire that.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm sorry, but I don't really understand the concept of “protecting from a global value”. :-/ I assume everything to be evaluated in a single context and could only add this note to the answer. For sure, almost anyone's edit regarding global vs local issues would be more reliable than mine.