# What is the the proper way to define a function from an expression?

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, hold

Say after some long computation we get an expression

```
expr=x^2
```

We do not know what the value of `expr` beforehand.
Now we want to turn this in a function. We can use either

```
f[x_]=expr
```

or

```
f[x_]:=Evaluate[expr]
```

as suggested in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31985/turn-expression-into-function).

However, when we do

```
f[x_]=Expand[expr]
```

or

```
f[x_]:=Evaluate[Expand[expr]]
```

The `Expand` will not have any effect.

Is there any way to make this work? Of course, we can define another function

```
g[x_]:=Expand[f[x]]
```

But is there any way to do it a bit more concisely?

Update:

If you do what suggested by Kuba in the comment, you get

```
In[89]:= With[{expr = expr}, f11[x_] := Expand[expr]]
In[90]:= f11[a + b]
Out[90]= x^2
In[91]:= ?? f11
Notebook$$34$907690`f11
f11[x$_]:=Expand[x^2]
```

Comment: I think `f[x_] = Expand[expr]` actually works fine. It expands `expr` and then turns `x` into a function slot. Just try it with `expr = (1 + x)^10` and then evaluate `f[y]` after defining `f`. Or were you expecting something different?

Comment: I was expecting to have `f[a+b]==Expand[(a+b)^2]=a^2+2 a b+b^2`

Comment: In that case I would say that the `g[x] := Expand[f[x]]` method is really the way to go here, because it makes the evaluation process easiest to follow. Any other method is just going to be confusing one way or another.

Comment: Closely related: [(69590)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69590/121)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry, I was too hasty in comments:

```
With[{expr = expr}, SetDelayed @@ Hold[f[x_], Expand[expr]]]
```

`SetDelayed @@ Hold` is needed because of: [Enforcing correct variable bindings and avoiding renamings for conflicting variables in nested scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/5478)

Comment: why not `With[{expr = Expand[expr]}, SetDelayed @@ Hold[f[x_], expr]]`

Comment: @AliHashmi Because the point is not to evaluate `Expand`. Compare `?f` in my and your case.

Comment: sorry i misinterpreted the question. I thought the purpose was for Evaluate to do its job before the definitions are saved.

Answer (score 6):

```
(f[x_] := Expand@#) &@expr
```

Comment: FYI, I'd accept that. This is what I usually do anyway :p

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple more possibilities. Using [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block):

```
Clear[f]
Block[{Expand}, f[x_] = Expand[expr]];
Definition[f]
```

> f[x_]=Expand[(1+x)^2]

Using [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With):

```
Clear[f]
With[{expr = expr, lhs = f[x_]},
    lhs := Expand[expr]
];
Definition[f]
```

> f[x_]:=Expand[(1+x)^2]

Answer (score 1):

This works, and the general idea is useful for other things too,

```
ToExpression["f[x_]:= Expand[" <> ToString[InputForm[expr]] <> "]"]
```

To test it, let's try something not already expanded,

```
expr = (1 + x)^2
```

Using the above way to make `f`, one finds that  `Definition[f] // InputForm` returns

```
f[x_] := Expand[(1 + x)^2]
```

as required. But we don't want to have to remember how to do all that, so let's just do it once for any `f` and any `expr`,

```
MakeFunction[f_, expr_]:= 
  ToExpression[ToString[f] <> "[x_]:= 
     Expand[" <> ToString[InputForm[expr]] <> "]"]
```

Next thing to do would be define `Options` for `MakeFunction`  so that instead of just `Expand`, you could instead use `Simplify`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Dear @ablmf you can use the following syntax in Mathematica.

```
f[x_]:=x^2;
```

When you input any desired value for `x`, Mathematica gives you its value in `f[x]`. Say, you want `f[2]`, Mathematica gives you 4

```
f[2]
```

> 4

You can also use it to obtain a list. Consider the following code

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
f[x_] := x^2;

Table[
f[x]
, {x, 0, 10}]
```

it gives you

> {0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100}

Comment: I'm sorry, but this isn't what OP asks for, is it?

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I asked.