# How can I create a shortcut to convert "normal Symbol" to Formal Symbol?

Tags: keyboard, built-in-symbols

I'd like to create a shortcut to convert a selected symbol, say `\[Delta]`, into its rough equivalent formal symbol (i.e., `\[FormalCapitalDelta]`).  That is, how does one create a shortcut to perform a front-end operation on a selected character?

This would only make sense for those single characters which have formal rough equivalents, so the shortcut should not do anything when multiple or a non-convertible single character is selected.

(comment:
I'm finding formal symbols to be handy for function definitions where SetDelayed isn't a great idea (or turning an expression into a function [Turning Expression into a Function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31985/turn-expression-into-function): e.g.,
instead of

```
f[x_] :=  expensiveSymbolicFunction[x]
```

use

```
f[\[FormalX]_] =  expensiveSymbolicFunction[\[FormalX]]
```

)

I find `\[FormalCapitalDelta]` (esc-.CapitalDelta-esc) tedious to type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An alternative is to create a notebook containing all the automatic replacements using `InputAutoReplacements`:

[image]

Test:

[image]

Comment: Nice.  I've never seen InputAutoReplacements before. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Here's an attempt:

```
Button["Formalize",
 NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  NotebookRead[EvaluationNotebook[]] /.
   s_String /; StringLength@s == 1 :>
    With[{res = ToExpression[
        "\\[Formal" <> StringReplace[
          CharacterName[s],
          {
           "LatinSmallLetter" ~~ l_ :> l, 
           "LatinCapitalLetter" ~~ l_ :> "Capital" <> l
           }
          ] <> "]"
        ]},
     ToString@res /; ! FailureQ@res
     ]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

As can be seen, clicking the button replaces all single-letter symbols in the current selection by their formal counterpart. This is done by first getting the name of the symbol using [`CharacterName`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CharacterName.html), then processing it to handle the different cases. Finally, it is converted back to the correct symbol using `ToString[ToExpression["\["<>name<>"]"]]`

Comment: Thanks @Lukas, Well done. This works nicely.   I'll accept as answered in a few days. I am hoping someone might offer a solution for the selected character only.

Comment: @CraigCarter I have updated the answer to only replace the contents that are explicitly selected

Comment: Very nice solution. Thanks